# Is there a way to upgrade the Ubuntu 12.04 OS to only 14.04. I inherited a system and Veeam 10 will not backup version 12.04 Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 12.04, upgrade, backup

The sites and webpages i have read are old and there is a question already but the final warning in the answer is to upgrade before 18.04 release? I am just trying to go up one version to first back up the entire server using Veeam before trying any other upgrades/updates. This is the company git server and losing anything would probably not be good for me.

Comment: Both Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 are no longer eligible for Community Support, which means that we no longer answer questions about them for free. Advice: Back up all data BEFORE trying to release-upgrade. And ask for a raise -- somebody left you a risky years-old mess to clean up. Were it my system, I would spin up a whole new 20.04 server and migrate the data across. A 12.04 system has nine-year-old hardware that should be replaced anyway.

Comment: Seems like the OP is having problems to backup data before upgrading.  The program Veeam is giving problems backing up, maybe someone here can help.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL and thus upgrade tools won't upgrade to it. However Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is still available, so yes you can upgrade from 12.04 LTS/ESM to Ubuntu 14.04 ESM, but EOL & ESM releases are off-topic here, with ESM releases supported via Ubuntu Advantage offered by Canonical.